# Spyder 5 menu icons overlap with menu entry label

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I recently updated to Spyder 5 via conda update and now i have the following two issues with the IDE:

- Icons of menu entries overlap with the menu entry text

[image: Sypder menu]

- i can not zoom in / out of plots in the plot pane anymore

[image]

What can i do to fix these issues? For the menu icon issue i tried different themes and different settings for the screen resolution, but nothing changed (despite what changed when changing those settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in version 5.0.0 , and it's resolved in `5.0.1`

here is the bug report in github:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15116

this update has not packaged in main conda channel, hopefully it will be packaged soon.

meanwhile, you can upgrade it from [forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder) :

```
 conda install -c conda-forge spyder
```

but if you want to wait to be tested and update it from main channel , after it became available in main channel you can upgrade it using:

```
conda install spyder=5.0.1
```

Comment: It returned in a later version, 5.1.5 I think. I had to uninstall it and am now using 5.1.3.

Comment: @FaustoArinosBarbuto seems like QA in spyder team is not the best. that's why anaconda has not packaged 5.1.x yet